# Xml Java DOM parser validation doesn't work

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to validate an xml with DOM parser. For some reason the parser doesn't recognize the specified namespace. What could be the problem?

It throws error:

```
Error: URI=null Line=5: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ioc'.
```

The code:

```
String outputString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"us-ascii\"?>\n" +
    "<ioc\n" +
    "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'\n" +
    "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'\n" +
    "xmlns=\"http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc\" >\n" +
    "</ioc>";

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(true);
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
factory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage",
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputString.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: i think you miss to set the Schema, validating is true but where is the Schema? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setSchema(javax.xml.validation.Schema)

Comment: I think it should use the schema specified by `xmlns="http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc"`

Comment: nope, is the xml namespace that use to match with schema but there is no autamatic download of the schema, consider off-line schenarious. If you want to validate your xml you need to load the schema and set into the factory

Comment: You would need to add an attribute `xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc http://example.com/schema.xsd"` I think to indicate the schema location to the parser. It could be a `file:/dir/subdir/schema.xsd` of course instead of an HTTP URL.

Comment: I tried setting `xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc" `and `xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc/ioc.xsd`, still not working ;(
It seems internal schema declaration doesnt work for some reason. It leaves me with less convenient external schema.

Comment: The `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute value should be a list of pairs of URLs where for each pair the first value is the URL of the namespace (in your case `http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc`) and the second URL provides the location of the schema for that namespace so `xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc/ioc.xsd"` is a meaningful example. Only one URL does not make sense.

Comment: Now, when I set schema by setSchema it throws `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/xxx/ioc.xsd; lineNumber: 72; columnNumber: 124; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'q1:param' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.`

Comment: Thanks Martin, now it recognizes the internal schema declaration but still throws the same error as mentioned before. The xsd seems to be missing schemaLocation.

Comment: `xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc/ioc.xsd http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc/TR/ http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc/TR/ioc-TR.xsd"` solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say what is wrong with the implementation you provided but here is a method I use to validate XML document against a schema (using only standard libraries)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


    /**
     * 
     * Purpose: validate an XML document against a schema
     * @param dom The org.w3c.dom.Document object representing the XML document
     * @param xsdPath The path to the XML schema file
     * @return True if the XML instance validates against the schema.
     */
    private static boolean validateXML(Document dom, String xsdPath){
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File(xsdPath));
        try {
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            // validate the DOM tree
            validator.validate(new DOMSource(dom));
        } catch (SAXException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add schemaLocation attribute with all required dependencies.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc 
http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc/ioc.xsd 
http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc/TR/ 
http://schemas.mandiant.com/2010/ioc/TR/ioc-TR.xsd"
```